# Generated column not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly simple SQL statement to get some results from a couple of tables. One of the columns is generated from an inline SQL statement. While I seem to be able to order by this column, trying to filter with it says that the column is invalid. Here is my code and error:

```
SELECT 
        e.Title as Title,
        -- Get earliest start time and latest end time
        (SELECT TOP 1 l.StartTime FROM Locations l WHERE l.EventID = e.EventID ORDER BY l.StartTime ASC) as EarliestStartTime,
        (SELECT TOP 1 l.EndTime FROM Locations l WHERE l.EventID = e.EventID ORDER BY l.EndTime DESC) as LatestEndTime

    FROM
        Events e
    WHERE
            e.UserID = @UserID
        AND LatestEndTime < DATEADD(DAY, GETDATE(), 1)
    ORDER BY
        EarliestStartTime ASC
```

Error:

```
Invalid column name 'LatestEndTime'.
```

If I remove the `AND LatestEndTime < DATEADD(DAY, GETDATE(), 1)` then the statement works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't refer to columns by alias in the `where` clause.  Either write it out, repeating the column definition:

```
WHERE  e.UserID = @UserID
       AND (SELECT TOP 1 l.EndTime FROM Locations l 
            WHERE l.EventID = e.EventID ORDER BY l.EndTime DESC) < 
            DATEADD(DAY, GETDATE(), 1)
```

Or use a subquery to name the column:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  e.Title as Title,
                -- Get earliest start time and latest end time
                (SELECT TOP 1 l.StartTime FROM Locations l
                 WHERE l.EventID = e.EventID ORDER BY l.StartTime ASC)
                 as EarliestStartTime,
                (SELECT TOP 1 l.EndTime FROM Locations l
                 WHERE l.EventID = e.EventID ORDER BY l.EndTime DESC)
                 as LatestEndTime
        from    Events e
        ) as SubQuery
WHERE   UserID = @UserID
        and LatestEndTime < DATEADD(DAY, GETDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution. I am actually having another error `Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.` but I think this is unrelated so I will Google and ask another question if needs be.

To expand upon your answer, I went with the second option, is there a better/more efficient/more standardised way of doing things? The reason I chose the second is in case of changes I wouldn't have to remember to update two SQL statements (the one in the column and the one in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that's why the second is preferable

Comment: Excellent, All working! And for anyone else getting my second error, the DATEADD function was in the wrong order, it should be `DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

May try to use e.LatestEndTime

It looks like your query is unable to determine the column LatestEndTime. It either don't exist or MySQL ist just checking in the false database since you used Locations l AND Events e in the query.

Comment: It doesn't exist as a column no, my understanding though was I could create any label when selecting a column, the `as LatestEndTime`. Tried with `e.` but no luck.

Comment: Question is tagged `sql-server`, MySQL actually does allow you to refer to column aliases in the `where` clause.